# Android intent redirect from user shows no UI

Tags: android, android-intent

I am running some kind of OAuth challenge on my mobile app and the flow is something like this:

1. User enters email address and clicks on "Sign In".
2. Goes to a browser -> presses a button and this action redirects him back to the sign in activity page.

As updated (in Edit 2), flow is from `SignInActivity` -> `Browser` -> `SignInactivity` (updated above).

This is the current flow. In the `SignInActivity`, I use the following `intent-filter`:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="com.alpha.beta" android:host="signin" />
</intent-filter>
```

The issue is that when the button is clicked and the focus returns back to the application — the SignIn view shows no UI.

---

**EDIT 1**

PS: The code is in c# as I am using Xamarin.

I have been asked to post some code but this is a bit hard. Here's what I have:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.AlphaBeta.AlphaBeta" android:versionName="1.1.1" android:versionCode="7">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <application android:name="AlphaBeta.Application" android:label="AlphaBeta" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:label="@string/appName" android:name="AlphaBeta.SignInActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation" android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:host="*" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.AlphaBeta" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.AlphaBeta" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.AlphaBeta" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.AlphaBeta" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.AlphaBeta" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.AlphaBeta" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="*" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.AlphaBeta" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.AlphaBeta" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.AlphaBeta" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.AlphaBeta" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.AlphaBeta" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.AlphaBeta" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="file" />
                <data android:host="*" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.AlphaBeta" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.AlphaBeta" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.AlphaBeta" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.AlphaBeta" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.AlphaBeta" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.AlphaBeta" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="content" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="com.AlphaBeta.AlphaBeta" android:host="sso" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
</manifest>
```

**SignInActivity.cs**

```
public class SignInActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();

        Android.Net.Uri redirectUriFromBrowser = this.Intent.Data;
        if (redirectUriFromBrowser != null)
        {
            // Redirect from user to continue with the SignIn flow
            string SignInToken = SignInTokenFromUri(redirectUriFromBrowser);
            if (singleSignOnToken == null)
            {
                HandleSignInFailure(this);
            }
            else
            {
                HandleSignInSuccess(this);
            }
        }
        else ...
    }

    ...
}
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

I am just wondering if the android intent-filter is somehow incorrect in the current use case. Please note the flow is from `SignInActivity` -> `Browser` -> `SignInactivity` (updated above).

---

**EDIT 3:**

Browser call:

```
Uri loginUri = Uri.Parse(user.SignInLink);
Intent SignInIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, loginUri);
this.StartActivity(SignInIntent);
```

Comment: Without the activity code there's no way to answer this question. Also post some of your manifest code.

Comment: Could you post your code please? also did you called the finish(); method?

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin please see if this suffices the use case.

Comment: @ivan Please see the updates. Thanks.

Comment: Where's the code that starts the browser part? When the user returns to the app does it actually start and show the Activity or not at all?

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin 

1. I can't really post a lot of the code here; but I have copy-pasted something that I use to start the browser.

2. The activity starts; I can see this if I use breakpoints.

Comment: Sorry can't help you without the code that actually displays whatever you need to see after the browser returns (HandleSignInSuccess , HandleSignInFailure). Since the Activity starts the filter seems to be correct at least to the point that it does trigger.

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin I think I may have confused you a bit. But currently, those functions are empty (deliberately just to check the flow). There's nothing going on. It's just blank.

Comment: Why would you expect something to see if they are empty? An Activity doesn't show a ui if you don't set a layout, at least not an meaningful one.

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin I see; apparently the content view is set in one of the else blocks; i was not able to notice that. That solves it. Thanks. :/ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you may notice from the comments, I was setting the UI in one of the if-else blocks and they weren't being called. This usually happens when you either write bad code or stare at the screen for more than unusual hours. Probably later.